# Are there any ways to compile C++ code during runtime?

Tags: c++, compilation, runtime

I have written a complex math library for JavaScript that features the ability to generate functions from strings of human-readable math expressions. Is there a way to achieve an equivalent of runtime-generated functions in C++?

Comment: Please restrict this to either C or C++ otherwise it's a little broad.

Comment: @FUZxxl There, it's fixed.

Comment: You could call out to a compiler ;). Seriously, I think the LLVM guys did some C++ JIT work at some point, you may look into that (I may remember wrong though).

Comment: There's also the [tiny C compiler](http://bellard.org/tcc/) which can be used to compile and run C code in your program, but it can't do C++, which is why I asked for clarification.

Comment: You could implement a C++ interpreter (lots of work though).

Comment: here's something I came across recently: an embedded javascript engine: http://duktape.org/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[FUZxxl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37778270/1621391)'s answer is right, and I recommend looking at the [Clang/LLVM](http://llvm.org) facility.

There is a basic *(not so helpful)* tutorial [file here](https://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/llvm/trunk/examples/HowToUseJIT/HowToUseJIT.cpp). And a broad tutorial on writing your [Language on LLVM](http://llvm.org/docs/tutorial/). You can load your generated library in your C++ App.

Unless, you have a performance critical component, you can employ the use of [ChaiScript](http://chaiscript.com) *(NB: I am in no way affiliated to it or the authors)*

Comment: Thanks for the helpful links, I will weigh my options. And yes the component will be performance critical. The reason I'm porting the library is because I want to increase the speed of my fractal-generating program.

Answer (score 3):

You can execute the C++ compiler, let it generate a shared library and load that into your program to run C++ code at runtime. Note that the details depend on what platform you are working on as Windows and POSIX have different mechanisms to load shared libraries.

Answer (score 0):

The 'compiled language way' is to define your grammar, build a parser, an AST (abstract syntax tree) and interpret/compile that. When you do this, you're essentially writing your own compiler/interpreter and it's a lot of fun. If you want to get it working easily, you might take a look at boost spirit.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation, but unfortunately the strings I want to compile won't be known until runtime, since I expect them from user input. I don't think an interpreter would be high enough performance for my needs.